# How to get two buttons to share half of the apps screen width with Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am trying to get two buttons to share the same width in a Relative Panel layout in Visual Studio with build `UWP` application but cannot seem to find resources or anything to show me how to do this.

Can any one help or give me some resources to go to? Please do not downgrade this question without suggestion.

Comment: Can you share some code what have you tried? 
And image of wanted result, please

Comment: I guess I understand. Why not using grid for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `RelativePanel` although the `Grid` solution presented by @al1Dima is also valid

```
<RelativePanel>
    <Button x:Name="LeftButton" Content="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.LeftOf="Divider" />
    <Border x:Name="Divider" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="RightButton" Content="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.RightOf="Divider" />
</RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `Grid`?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Those two buttons will get 50% of `Grid`'s `Width`.

You also can define columns like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

So first `Button` will take 2/5 of `Grid`'s `Width` and another one will take 3/5 of `Width`